# How to remove certain items from a Stack

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I have a homework problem in which I need to remove all the green items from the stack.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Pex
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Stack stack1 = new Stack(); 

addPez(stack1);
removeGreen(stack1);
System.out.println(printStack(stack2));
}

public void addPez(Stack stack1)
{
    stack1.push("yellow");
    stack1.push("red");
    stack1.push("green");
    stack1.push("green");
    stack1.push("yellow");
    stack1.push("yellow");
    stack1.push("red");
    stack1.push("green");
}

public static void removeGreen(Stack stack1)
{
Stack temp = new Stack();
while (!stack1.isEmpty()){
  String check = (String)(stack1.pop());
    if(check.equals("green")){
    stack1.pop();}
    else{
    temp.push(check);}
}
Stack stack2 = new Stack();
while (!temp.isEmpty()){
  String tmp = stack1.pop();
  stack2.push(tmp);}
}

public static void printStack(Stack stack2)
{
Stack xerox = stack2.clone();
while (!xerox.isEmpty()){
  System.out.println(xerox.pop());}
}
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I think I'm almost there.

I also need to figure out why I am getting some errors.

Here are the errors:

```
Pex.java:10: non-static method addPez(Stack) cannot be referenced from a static context
addPez(stack1);
^
Pex.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable stack2
location: class Pex
System.out.println(printStack(stack2));
                              ^

Pex.java:39: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
  String tmp = stack1.pop();
                         ^

Pex.java:45: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: Stack
Stack xerox = stack2.clone();
                          ^

./Stack.java:69: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable stack1
location: class Stack
    stack2 = (Stack)(stack1.clone());
                     ^

5 errors
```

Comment: Make `addPez` as `static` you can not access a non static methid from a static context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack stack1 = new Stack();

    addPez(stack1);
    removeGreen(stack1);
    printStack(stack1); //stack2 is not defined and remove println statement
}

public static void addPez(Stack stack1) {//make addPez as static
    stack1.push("yellow");
    stack1.push("red");
    stack1.push("green");
    stack1.push("green");
    stack1.push("yellow");
    stack1.push("yellow");
    stack1.push("red");
    stack1.push("green");
}

public static void removeGreen(Stack stack1) {
    Stack temp = new Stack();
    while (!stack1.isEmpty()) {
        String check = (String) (stack1.pop());
        if (check.equals("green")) {
            //stack1.pop();
        } else {
            temp.push(check);
        }
    }
    //Stack stack2 = new Stack();
    while (!temp.isEmpty()) {
        String tmp = (String)temp.pop();
        stack1.push(tmp);
    }
}

public static void printStack(Stack stack1) {
    Stack xerox = (Stack)stack1.clone();
    while (!xerox.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(xerox.pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed the code and now you can run it

Comment: The problem is i need to print out the stack without the greens. This only prints out the greens, which is why i had stack2. Do i need stack2 to print out non green stack?

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You are calling non-static method addPez(...) in static one.Change addPez() to static or call it in any non static method
**2)** `System.out.println(printStack(stack2));` What is stack2? I didn't find it in your code
**3)** `stack1.pop();` pop() method return type is Object.So you should do like this
 `String tmp = (String)stack1.pop();`
This is type casting of object to String(In your case It is OK but it is not recommended)
**4) & 5)**
    xerox = (Stack)stack2.clone(); you need to do like that

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Pex.java:10: non-static method addPez(Stack) cannot be referenced 
> from a static context addPez(stack1);
> ```

It seems like you're using this incorrectly and need to construct an object to use `addPez`, or add `static` to the method header to use it not in the `objectName.methodName();` manner.

**Edit:** Wow, stackOverflow is quick. I gotta' get my head in the game. I think other people provided your answer though. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`public void addPez(Stack stack1)` should be `public static void addPez(Stack stack1)`

There is no variable called `stack2` in you main method, did you mean `stack1`??

`System.out.println(printStack(stack2));` should be `System.out.println(printStack(stack1));`?

This actually will cause another error, as `printStack` is decleared as returning `void`, which `System.out.println()` won't like.  Instead, just call the print method `printStack(stack1);` directly, as it's dumping it's results to the screen any way...

You should be casting the return type of your stack, `String tmp = stack1.pop();` should be `String tmp = (String)stack1.pop();`

`Stack xerox = stack2.clone();` is the same problem as the last one, in essence, should be `Stack xerox = (Stack)stack2.clone();`

**Ideas**...

Doing blind casts is generally a bad idea (`(String)stack1.pop()`).  Now in your simple program, it's probably not a big deal, but encourages bad practices.

You should be taking advantage of [Java's Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) support

So, instead of `Stack stack1 = new Stack();` you should be using `Stack<String> stack1 = new Stack<String>();`

Instead of `public static void addPez(Stack stack1)` you should be using `public static void addPez(Stack<String> stack1)`

Instead of `public static void removeGreen(Stack stack1)` you should be using `public static void removeGreen(Stack<String> stack1)`

Instead of `Stack temp = new Stack();` and `Stack stack2 = new Stack();` you should be using `Stack temp = new Stack<String>();` and `Stack stack2 = new Stack<String>();`

Instead of `public static void printStack(Stack stack2)` you should be using `public static void printStack(Stack<String> stack2)`

This means you no longer need the case in the remove method (`String check = (String) (stack1.pop())`) which becomes `String check = stack1.pop();`

This basically means that your `Stack` can only ever contain `String` objects and removes any possibility of someone passing you the wrong type of stack.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pop again if the element is "green".

```
while (!stack1.isEmpty()){
    String check = (String)(stack1.pop());
    if(!check.equals("green")) {
        temp.push(check);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could see these issue you should resolve to correct your program:

1. `public void addPez(Stack stack1)` should be `static`

   ```
   public static void addPez(Stack stack1)
   ```
2. `System.out.println(printStack(stack2));` -- No `stack2` variable defined in scope of `main` method.
3. In method `removeGreen(Stack stack1)` you have not casted the result of `pop` to `String`

   ```
   String tmp = (String)stack1.pop();
   ```
4. In method `printStack(Stack stack2)` you have not casted the result of `clone` to `Stack`

   ```
   Stack xerox = (Stack)stack2.clone();
   ```

---

These correction will make the program compilable but you can make your program much better by some more changes that will improve the time and space performance and it's logic also.

Change your `removeGreen` method to following:

```
public static Stack removeGreen(Stack stack1)
{
    Stack temp = new Stack();
    while (!stack1.isEmpty())
    {
        String check = (String)(stack1.pop());
        if( ! check.equals("green"))
        {
            temp.push(check);
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Within `main` method change this line `removeGreen(stack1);` to following:

```
stack1 = removeGreen(stack1);
```

and, one more

Use [Generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java). i.e

```
Stack<String> aStack = new Stack<String>();
```

is much better than

```
Stack aStack = new Stack();
```